# Write '%' symbol in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am doing a script that calculates the % free space on our hosts.

```
$percent = [math]::Round($AvailableMemory * 100 / $TotalMemory)
```

It gives me the correct number, but when I want to print the $percent variable with the value + '%' it do not let me.

How can I print the value with this simbol? For example 33%, 55% ...

Best regards

Comment: Define "does not let me". What are your trying and what is the actual error message you get?

Comment: For example I tried: $test = $percent+'%' also $test = $percent '%'. And the error is: Cannot convert value "%" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Try `"{0:p}" -f $percent`, you have to change your calculation, though. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx

Comment: Thank you Lenniey! I just needed to add a  "/100" in the $percent form and the {0:p} worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is used to concatenate strings, but it is also used to do math operations. Since the result of your calculation is a float, powershell tries to convert your `%` into a float as well, so it can add it to the calculated value.

You can append the `%` sign by converting your float into a string first:

```
$percent.toString() + '%'
```

Other possible notations:

```
"$percent" + "%"
"$percent%"
```

The result is always the same.

Alternatively, you can use string formatting:

```
"{0}%" -f $percent
```

will just use the value as it is. If you want a more uniform output you can specify how the value should be handled:

```
"{0:N2}%" -f $percent
```

will always output two decimal values, even for round numbers.

Here is a nice summary of the [formatting options](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).